# Discord Bot error when playing music - discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots, ytdl

I made Music Bot and want to play music with yt-search and ytdl-core, everything works for a short time but then I get an error and I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
const {videos} = await yts(message.content);
if (!videos.length) return message.reply("No songs were found!");
const song = {
    title: videos[0].title,
    stream: ytdl(videos[0].url, {filter: "audioonly"}),
    url: videos[0].url
};
const resource = createAudioResource(song.stream)
player.play(resource);
bot.connection.subscribe(player);
```

After a short time I get the following error:

```
N [Error]: aborted
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:691:14)
    at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:407:19)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at node:net:687:12
    at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:580:7) {
  resource: j {
    playStream: OggDemuxer {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _remainder: null,
      _head: null,
      _bitstream: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: [Function: bound onwrite]
    },
    edges: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    metadata: null,
    volume: undefined,
    encoder: undefined,
    audioPlayer: H {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _state: [Object],
      subscribers: [Array],
      behaviors: [Object],
      debug: [Function (anonymous)],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    playbackDuration: 56740,
    started: true,
    silencePaddingFrames: 5,
    silenceRemaining: -1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who gets the same error, just switch from ytdl-core to [play-dl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/play-dl) with this libary everything works fine!